# Can't change layout in JS lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE: https://jsfiddle.net/ymLd152e/**
It's not working 100% cleanly (had to modify some things), but i think it's good enough for demonstration.

---

I have found a free javascript lightbox, and integrated it into my webpage. It looks like this when image is opened:

[image]

For a couple of days now i'm trying to move the picture counter and the X under the image, to the same line where the capture is. But i'm not good enough in JS.

The HTML layout of the lighbox gets done by JS & JQuery. I have found the variables, but when i change the values from *appendTo(wrapper)* to *appendTo(image)* the elements simply disappear - in the browser and in the  HTML shown in the inspector (FireBug).

Could anyone help me with a clue what i'm missing here? As i said, i've been studying the script for a couple of days now, and understand many things, but the solution is eluding me still.

Here's the script (sorry if it's a tad long - i just need a nudge in the right direction):

```
    /*
    By André Rinas, www.andreknieriem.de
    Available for use under the MIT License
*/

;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.simpleLightbox = function(options) {

        var options = $.extend({
            overlay: true,
            spinner: true,
            nav: true,
            navText: ['&lsaquo;', '&rsaquo;'],
            captions: true,
            captionDelay: 0,
            captionSelector: 'img',
            captionType: 'attr',
            captionsData: 'title',
            captionPosition: 'outside',
            close: true,
            closeText: '×',
            swipeClose: true,
            showCounter: true,
            fileExt: false,
            animationSlide: true,
            animationSpeed: 100,
            preloading: true,
            enableKeyboard: true,
            loop: false,
            rel: false,
            docClose: true,
            swipeTolerance: 50,
            className: 'simple-lightbox',
            widthRatio: 0.85,
            heightRatio: 0.9,
            disableRightClick: false,
            disableScroll: true,
            alertError: true,
            alertErrorMessage: 'Image not found, next image will be loaded',
            additionalHtml: false,
            history: true
        }, options);

        // global variables
        var touchDevice = ('ontouchstart' in window),
            pointerEnabled = window.navigator.pointerEnabled || window.navigator.msPointerEnabled,
            touched = function(event) {
                if (touchDevice) return true;
                if (!pointerEnabled || typeof event === 'undefined' || typeof event.pointerType === 'undefined') return false;
                if (typeof event.MSPOINTER_TYPE_MOUSE !== 'undefined') {
                    if (event.MSPOINTER_TYPE_MOUSE != event.pointerType) return true;
                } else {
                    if (event.pointerType != 'mouse') return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
            swipeDiff = 0,
            swipeYDiff = 0,
            curImg = $(),
            transPrefix = function() {
                var s = document.body || document.documentElement;
                s = s.style;
                if (s.WebkitTransition === '') return '-webkit-';
                if (s.MozTransition === '') return '-moz-';
                if (s.OTransition === '') return '-o-';
                if (s.transition === '') return '';
                return false;
            },
            opened = false,
            loaded = [],
            getRelated = function(rel, jqObj) {
                var $related = $(jqObj.selector).filter(function() {
                    return ($(this).attr('rel') === rel);
                });
                return $related;
            },
            objects = (options.rel && options.rel !== false) ? getRelated(options.rel, this) : this,
            transPrefix = transPrefix(),
            globalScrollbarwidth = 0,
            canTransisions = (transPrefix !== false) ? true : false,
            supportsPushState = ('pushState' in history),
            historyhasChanged = false,
            historyUpdateTimeout,
            winLoc = window.location,
            getHash = function() {
                return winLoc.hash.substring(1);
            },
            initialHash = getHash(),
            updateHash = function() {
                var hash = getHash(),
                    newHash = 'pid=' + (index + 1);
                var newURL = winLoc.href.split('#')[0] + '#' + newHash;

                if (supportsPushState) {
                    history[historyhasChanged ? 'replaceState' : 'pushState']('', document.title, newURL);
                } else {
                    if (historyhasChanged) {
                        winLoc.replace(newURL);
                    } else {
                        winLoc.hash = newHash;
                    }
                }
                historyhasChanged = true;
            },
            resetHash = function() {
                if (supportsPushState) {
                    history.pushState('', document.title, winLoc.pathname + winLoc.search);
                } else {
                    winLoc.hash = '';
                }
                clearTimeout(historyUpdateTimeout);

            },
            updateURL = function() {
                if (!historyhasChanged) {
                    updateHash(); // first time
                } else {
                    historyUpdateTimeout = setTimeout(updateHash, 800);
                }
            },
            prefix = 'simplelb',
            overlay = $('<div>').addClass('sl-overlay'),
            closeBtn = $('<button>').addClass('sl-close').html(options.closeText),
            spinner = $('<div>').addClass('sl-spinner').html('<div></div>'),
            nav = $('<div>').addClass('sl-navigation').html('<button class="sl-prev">' + options.navText[0] + '</button><button class="sl-next">' + options.navText[1] + '</button>'),
            counter = $('<div>').addClass('sl-counter').html('<span class="sl-current"></span>/<span class="sl-total"></span>'),
            animating = false,
            index = 0,
            caption = $('<div>').addClass('sl-caption pos-' + options.captionPosition),
            image = $('<div>').addClass('sl-image'),
            wrapper = $('<div>').addClass('sl-wrapper').addClass(options.className),
            isValidLink = function(element) {
                if (!options.fileExt) return true;
                return $(element).prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'a' && (new RegExp('\.(' + options.fileExt + ')$', 'i')).test($(element).attr('href'));
            },
            setup = function() {
                if (options.close) closeBtn.appendTo(wrapper);
                if (options.showCounter) {
                    if (objects.length > 1) {
                        counter.appendTo(wrapper);
                        counter.find('.sl-total').text(objects.length);
                    }
                }
                if (options.nav) nav.appendTo(wrapper);
                if (options.spinner) spinner.appendTo(wrapper);
            },
            openImage = function(elem) {
                elem.trigger($.Event('show.simplelightbox'));
                if (options.disableScroll) globalScrollbarwidth = handleScrollbar('hide');
                wrapper.appendTo('body');
                image.appendTo(wrapper);
                if (options.overlay) overlay.appendTo($('body'));
                animating = true;
                index = objects.index(elem);
                curImg = $('<img/>')
                    .hide()
                    .attr('src', elem.attr('href'));
                if (loaded.indexOf(elem.attr('href')) == -1) {
                    loaded.push(elem.attr('href'));
                }
                image.html('').attr('style', '');
                curImg.appendTo(image);
                addEvents();
                overlay.fadeIn('fast');
                $('.sl-close').fadeIn('fast');
                spinner.show();
                nav.fadeIn('fast');
                $('.sl-wrapper .sl-counter .sl-current').text(index + 1);
                counter.fadeIn('fast');
                adjustImage();
                if (options.preloading) preload();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    elem.trigger($.Event('shown.simplelightbox'));
                }, options.animationSpeed);
            },
            adjustImage = function(dir) {
                if (!curImg.length) return;
                var tmpImage = new Image(),
                    windowWidth = $(window).width() * options.widthRatio,
                    windowHeight = $(window).height() * options.heightRatio;
                tmpImage.src = curImg.attr('src');

                $(tmpImage).bind('error', function(ev) {
                    //no image was found
                    objects.eq(index).trigger($.Event('error.simplelightbox'));
                    animating = false;
                    opened = true;
                    spinner.hide();
                    if (options.alertError) {
                        alert(options.alertErrorMessage);
                    }
                    if (dir == 1 || dir == -1) {
                        loadImage(dir);
                    } else {
                        loadImage(1);
                    }
                    return;
                });


                tmpImage.onload = function() {
                    if (typeof dir !== 'undefined') {
                        objects.eq(index)
                            .trigger($.Event('changed.simplelightbox'))
                            .trigger($.Event((dir === 1 ? 'nextDone' : 'prevDone') + '.simplelightbox'));
                    }

                    // history
                    if (options.history) {
                        updateURL();
                    }

                    if (loaded.indexOf(curImg.attr('src')) == -1) {
                        loaded.push(curImg.attr('src'));
                    }
                    var imageWidth = tmpImage.width,
                        imageHeight = tmpImage.height;

                    if (imageWidth > windowWidth || imageHeight > windowHeight) {
                        var ratio = imageWidth / imageHeight > windowWidth / windowHeight ? imageWidth / windowWidth : imageHeight / windowHeight;
                        imageWidth /= ratio;
                        imageHeight /= ratio;
                    }

                    $('.sl-image').css({
                        'top': ($(window).height() - imageHeight) / 2 + 'px',
                        'left': ($(window).width() - imageWidth - globalScrollbarwidth) / 2 + 'px'
                    });
                    spinner.hide();
                    curImg
                        .css({
                            'width': imageWidth + 'px',
                            'height': imageHeight + 'px'
                        })
                        .fadeIn('fast');
                    opened = true;
                    var cSel = (options.captionSelector == 'self') ? objects.eq(index) : objects.eq(index).find(options.captionSelector);
                    var captionText;
                    if (options.captionType == 'data') {
                        captionText = cSel.data(options.captionsData);
                    } else if (options.captionType == 'text') {
                        captionText = cSel.html();
                    } else {
                        captionText = cSel.prop(options.captionsData);
                    }

                    if (!options.loop) {
                        if (index === 0) {
                            $('.sl-prev').hide();
                        }
                        if (index >= objects.length - 1) {
                            $('.sl-next').hide();
                        }
                        if (index > 0) {
                            $('.sl-prev').show();
                        }
                        if (index < objects.length - 1) {
                            $('.sl-next').show();
                        }
                    }

                    if (objects.length == 1) $('.sl-prev, .sl-next').hide();

                    if (dir == 1 || dir == -1) {
                        var css = {
                            'opacity': 1.0
                        };
                        if (options.animationSlide) {
                            if (canTransisions) {
                                slide(0, 100 * dir + 'px');
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    slide(options.animationSpeed / 1000, 0 + 'px'), 50
                                });
                            } else {
                                css.left = parseInt($('.sl-image').css('left')) + 100 * dir + 'px';
                            }
                        }

                        $('.sl-image').animate(css, options.animationSpeed, function() {
                            animating = false;
                            setCaption(captionText);
                        });
                    } else {
                        animating = false;
                        setCaption(captionText);
                    }
                    if (options.additionalHtml && $('.sl-additional-html').length === 0) {
                        $('<div>').html(options.additionalHtml).addClass('sl-additional-html').appendTo($('.sl-image'));
                    }
                };
            },
            setCaption = function(captiontext) {
                if (captiontext !== '' && typeof captiontext !== "undefined" && options.captions) {
                    caption.html(captiontext).hide().appendTo($('.sl-image')).delay(options.captionDelay).fadeIn('fast');
                }
            },
            slide = function(speed, pos) {
                var styles = {};
                styles[transPrefix + 'transform'] = 'translateX(' + pos + ')';
                styles[transPrefix + 'transition'] = transPrefix + 'transform ' + speed + 's linear';
                $('.sl-image').css(styles);
            },
            addEvents = function() {
                // resize/responsive
                $(window).on('resize.' + prefix, adjustImage);

                // close lightbox on close btn
                $(document).on('click.' + prefix + ' touchstart.' + prefix, '.sl-close', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (opened) {
                        close();
                    }
                });

                if (options.history) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(window).on('hashchange.' + prefix, function() {
                            if (opened) {
                                if (getHash() === initialHash) {
                                    close();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }, 40);
                }

                // nav-buttons
                nav.on('click.' + prefix, 'button', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    swipeDiff = 0;
                    loadImage($(this).hasClass('sl-next') ? 1 : -1);
                });

                // touchcontrols
                var swipeStart = 0,
                    swipeEnd = 0,
                    swipeYStart = 0,
                    swipeYEnd = 0,
                    mousedown = false,
                    imageLeft = 0;

                image
                    .on('touchstart.' + prefix + ' mousedown.' + prefix, function(e) {
                        if (mousedown) return true;
                        if (canTransisions) imageLeft = parseInt(image.css('left'));
                        mousedown = true;
                        swipeStart = e.originalEvent.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
                        swipeYStart = e.originalEvent.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
                        return false;
                    })
                    .on('touchmove.' + prefix + ' mousemove.' + prefix + ' pointermove MSPointerMove', function(e) {
                        if (!mousedown) return true;
                        e.preventDefault();
                        swipeEnd = e.originalEvent.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
                        swipeYEnd = e.originalEvent.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
                        swipeDiff = swipeStart - swipeEnd;
                        swipeYDiff = swipeYStart - swipeYEnd;
                        if (options.animationSlide) {
                            if (canTransisions) slide(0, -swipeDiff + 'px');
                            else image.css('left', imageLeft - swipeDiff + 'px');
                        }
                    })
                    .on('touchend.' + prefix + ' mouseup.' + prefix + ' touchcancel.' + prefix + ' mouseleave.' + prefix + ' pointerup pointercancel MSPointerUp MSPointerCancel', function(e) {
                        if (mousedown) {
                            mousedown = false;
                            var possibleDir = true;
                            if (!options.loop) {
                                if (index === 0 && swipeDiff < 0) {
                                    possibleDir = false;
                                }
                                if (index >= objects.length - 1 && swipeDiff > 0) {
                                    possibleDir = false;
                                }
                            }
                            if (Math.abs(swipeDiff) > options.swipeTolerance && possibleDir) {
                                loadImage(swipeDiff > 0 ? 1 : -1);
                            } else if (options.animationSlide) {
                                if (canTransisions) slide(options.animationSpeed / 1000, 0 + 'px');
                                else image.animate({
                                    'left': imageLeft + 'px'
                                }, options.animationSpeed / 2);
                            }

                            if (options.swipeClose && Math.abs(swipeYDiff) > 50 && Math.abs(swipeDiff) < options.swipeTolerance) {
                                close();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            },
            removeEvents = function() {
                nav.off('click', 'button');
                $(document).off('click.' + prefix, '.sl-close');
                $(window).off('resize.' + prefix);
                $(window).off('hashchange.' + prefix);
            },
            preload = function() {
                var next = (index + 1 < 0) ? objects.length - 1 : (index + 1 >= objects.length - 1) ? 0 : index + 1,
                    prev = (index - 1 < 0) ? objects.length - 1 : (index - 1 >= objects.length - 1) ? 0 : index - 1;
                $('<img />').attr('src', objects.eq(next).attr('href')).on('load', function() {
                    if (loaded.indexOf($(this).attr('src')) == -1) {
                        loaded.push($(this).attr('src'));
                    }
                    objects.eq(index).trigger($.Event('nextImageLoaded.simplelightbox'));
                });
                $('<img />').attr('src', objects.eq(prev).attr('href')).on('load', function() {
                    if (loaded.indexOf($(this).attr('src')) == -1) {
                        loaded.push($(this).attr('src'));
                    }
                    objects.eq(index).trigger($.Event('prevImageLoaded.simplelightbox'));
                });

            },
            loadImage = function(dir) {
                objects.eq(index)
                    .trigger($.Event('change.simplelightbox'))
                    .trigger($.Event((dir === 1 ? 'next' : 'prev') + '.simplelightbox'));

                var newIndex = index + dir;
                if (animating || (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= objects.length) && options.loop === false) return;
                index = (newIndex < 0) ? objects.length - 1 : (newIndex > objects.length - 1) ? 0 : newIndex;
                $('.sl-wrapper .sl-counter .sl-current').text(index + 1);
                var css = {
                    'opacity': 0
                };
                if (options.animationSlide) {
                    if (canTransisions) slide(options.animationSpeed / 1000, (-100 * dir) - swipeDiff + 'px');
                    else css.left = parseInt($('.sl-image').css('left')) + -100 * dir + 'px';
                }

                $('.sl-image').animate(css, options.animationSpeed, function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // fadeout old image
                        var elem = objects.eq(index);
                        curImg
                            .attr('src', elem.attr('href'));
                        if (loaded.indexOf(elem.attr('href')) == -1) {
                            spinner.show();
                        }
                        $('.sl-caption').remove();
                        adjustImage(dir);
                        if (options.preloading) preload();
                    }, 100);
                });
            },
            close = function() {
                if (animating) return;
                var elem = objects.eq(index),
                    triggered = false;

                elem.trigger($.Event('close.simplelightbox'));
                if (options.history) {
                    resetHash();
                }
                $('.sl-image img, .sl-overlay, .sl-close, .sl-navigation, .sl-image .sl-caption, .sl-counter').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    if (options.disableScroll) handleScrollbar('show');
                    $('.sl-wrapper, .sl-overlay').remove();
                    removeEvents();
                    if (!triggered) elem.trigger($.Event('closed.simplelightbox'));
                    triggered = true;
                });
                curImg = $();
                opened = false;
                animating = false;
            },
            handleScrollbar = function(type) {
                var scrollbarWidth = 0;
                if (type == 'hide') {
                    var fullWindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
                    if (!fullWindowWidth) {
                        var documentElementRect = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
                        fullWindowWidth = documentElementRect.right - Math.abs(documentElementRect.left);
                    }
                    if (document.body.clientWidth < fullWindowWidth) {
                        var scrollDiv = document.createElement('div'),
                            padding = parseInt($('body').css('padding-right'), 10);
                        scrollDiv.className = 'sl-scrollbar-measure';
                        $('body').append(scrollDiv);
                        scrollbarWidth = scrollDiv.offsetWidth - scrollDiv.clientWidth;
                        $(document.body)[0].removeChild(scrollDiv);
                        $('body').data('padding', padding);
                        if (scrollbarWidth > 0) {
                            $('body').addClass('hidden-scroll').css({
                                'padding-right': padding + scrollbarWidth
                            });
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $('body').removeClass('hidden-scroll').css({
                        'padding-right': $('body').data('padding')
                    });
                }
                return scrollbarWidth;
            };

        // events
        setup();

        // open lightbox
        objects.on('click.' + prefix, function(e) {
            if (isValidLink(this)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (animating) return false;
                openImage($(this));
            }
        });

        // close on click on doc
        $(document).on('click.' + prefix + ' touchstart.' + prefix, function(e) {
            if (opened) {
                if ((options.docClose && $(e.target).closest('.sl-image').length === 0 && $(e.target).closest('.sl-navigation').length === 0)) {
                    close();
                }
            }
        });

        // disable rightclick
        if (options.disableRightClick) {
            $(document).on('contextmenu', '.sl-image img', function(e) {
                return false;
            });
        }


        // keyboard-control
        if (options.enableKeyboard) {
            $(document).on('keyup.' + prefix, function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                swipeDiff = 0;
                // keyboard control only if lightbox is open
                if (opened) {
                    var key = e.keyCode;
                    if (key == 27) {
                        close();
                    }
                    if (key == 37 || e.keyCode == 39) {
                        loadImage(e.keyCode == 39 ? 1 : -1);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Public methods
        this.open = function(elem) {
            elem = elem || $(this[0]);
            openImage(elem);
        };

        this.next = function() {
            loadImage(1);
        };

        this.prev = function() {
            loadImage(-1);
        };

        this.close = function() {
            close();
        };

        this.destroy = function() {
            $(document).unbind('click.' + prefix).unbind('keyup.' + prefix);
            close();
            $('.sl-overlay, .sl-wrapper').remove();
            this.off('click');
        };

        this.refresh = function() {
            this.destroy();
            $(this.selector).simpleLightbox(options);
        };

        return this;

    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Huh, it is too much code... :) Anyway, you shouldn't change plugin it self... Try to inspect generated HTML, and maybe you could solve it just by using CSS?

Comment: Can't do it with CSS, because i need the counter and the X to be inside the image element (or rather below it) and stay flexible to windows size. Can be done only in HTML, but the HTML is generated in the script, AFAICS after prefix = 'simplelb'.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle of this?

Comment: Yeah, just give me a bit of time - i'll need to strip down the code.

Comment: Gabriel, here a jsfiddle. Though not working 100% (IDK why), it shows the lightbox and the full code in context. https://jsfiddle.net/ymLd152e/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the CSS.

Change `top: 30px` to `bottom:30px` in both `.sl-wrapper .sl-close` and `.sl-wrapper .sl-counter`

This change tells the element to measure up 30px from the bottom, rather than 30px down from the top.  You might like to adjust those numbers to suit, and you'll notices there are `left` and `right` values you might like to tweak as well.

So, the new CSS changes looks like:

```
/* line 54, ../sass/simplelightbox.scss */
.sl-wrapper .sl-close {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    z-index: 1015;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-right: -14px;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    line-height: 44px;
    font-family: Arial, Baskerville, monospace;
    color: rgb(218,218,218);
    font-size: 2.6rem;
}

/* line 70, ../sass/simplelightbox.scss */
.sl-wrapper .sl-counter {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    z-index: 1015;
    color: rgb(222,222,222);
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}
```

Here's your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ufu2hx9c/1/

Comment: Thanks K, but i believe you misunderstood. I don't want these elements to be at the bottom of the page - that's easy to do in CSS, because the elements are still in the same parent-element (wrapper). Instead i want them to be just under the image, where the caption is (positioned relative to the image). Very sorry that it was unclear in my posting - i've updated my text.