# Pls explain this JQuery line to me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand how this line in a lighbox script works:

```
overlay = $('<div>').addClass('sl-overlay'),
```

It's generating HTML, but I fail to understand where exactly the HTML gets inserted, and what part of this code tells the browser the location were the new element gets inserted.

What confuses me more is, that I thought that "div" is a selector in this case. But there are many divs in the document. It's not like every div gets the class "sl-overlay", so much is clear.

Comment: Without more context it is not shown where that gets inserted. `$()` also supports html strings as argument. Read `$()` docs

Comment: Theres a documentation for this: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/
Your piece of code creates a `<div>` and adds a class. That's it.

Comment: You could take a look at the complete script here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796704/cant-change-layout-in-js-lightbox

Comment: @Dennis: But at what location? There are many elements in the initial HTML code.

Comment: You can't tell from your piece of code. It only creates a div but doens't insert it yet. Look for `append`, `appendTo`, `prepend`, `prependTo`

Comment: I dont get the downvotes. the question is pretty clear and ```$('<div>')``` is not that common. Maybe you can add more context. For example the whole function

Comment: @Kevin: It's not yet in a function, just in the beginning where all global variables are set. Here is the full script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796704/cant-change-layout-in-js-lightbox

Comment: The div-overlay is appended in line 155 and it's simply added to the end of the body:
`if (options.overlay) overlay.appendTo($('body'));`

Comment: @sveto :  `overlay = $('<div>').addClass('sl-overlay')` if this is what you are talking about then, this creates a new div adds class `sl-overlay` to the newly created div and assigns it to variable overlay

Comment: Please have a look at the jQuery documentation about dom manipulation: https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff `$(htmlString)` is extremely common and is also well documented

Comment: Ahah I guess is I need to revise my jQuery then. And indeed documented : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: I understand now, thanks! The actual problem is another of these VARs. The var "counter" gets later "appendTo(wrapper)" as default, but when i change that to "appendTo(image)" (which is another defined VAR), it doesn't get inserted in the HTML at all. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('<div>')` create a new div element, read about it [jquery Documantation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-element), search for **Creating New Elements** section.

Therefore your piece of code :

`overlay = $('<div>').addClass('sl-overlay'),`

creates a new `div` element assigns adds a class `sl-overlay` and then assigns it to the vaiable overlay which can be used later,

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var overlay = $('<div>').addClass('sl-overlay');
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('body').append(overlay);
  })

})
```

```css
.sl-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Show Modal</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You create a `div` element, add a className, save it in the `overlay` variable to insert it later in the DOM. **It's not inserted yet in the DOM**.

In VanillaJS, this is like:

```
var overlay = document.createElement('div');
overlay.className = 'sl-overlay';
// do something with the overlay variable ...
```

Comment: That's what i needed to know i think. Up until the "appendTo()" there is nothing changed in the HTML. That wasn't quite clear before.

Answer (score 1):

the produced HTML isn't appended on screen, you should end this with something in the likes of :

```
$('body').append(overlay);
```

or :

```
overlay = $('<div>').addClass('sl-overlay').appendTo('body');
```

...

`$('<div>')` - is a short for creating a div element in jquery
`.addClass('...')` - means adding a class to the produced element

jquery is usually returning the element after creating / modifying it, which allows you to chain commands:

`$('.selector').css().appendTo().next().remove();`